# T-SQL DATEDIFF returns Years and Month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have the following request :

> Find people with more than 79 Years and 3 Month.

Suppose i have 3 persons with the following datebirth :

```
1941-01-01
1941-04-01
1941-12-01
```

How to get the one that my request need ?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure if you search for something like `age calculation sql` you'll find many helpful sources.

Comment: More than 79 Years 3 Months of what? This reads like a homework question. :/

Comment: Of Age , obviuosly.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @ThresholdDate DATE

-- go from "today" (SYSDATETIME), and subtract 79 years and 3 months from that date
SELECT @ThresholdDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -3, DATEADD(YEAR, -79, SYSDATETIME()))

-- now select everyone with a birthday before that date
SELECT (list-of-columns)
FROM dbo.YourTableNameHere
WHERE BirthDate <= @ThresholdDate;
```